# How to affect players with a scoreboard score of 0

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am creating a simple thing for a project I am creating. I want to remove the "night_vision" effect from players with a "holdingTorch" score of 0.
I would think it would be done like this but it's not working:
`/execute @a[score_holdingTorch=0] ~ ~ ~ effect @p night_vision 0`
It keeps saying
`The entity UUID provided is in an invalid format`

Comment: Are there any players with a `holdingTorch` score of 0? Keep in mind that a score that has not yet been set is not 0.

Answer (score 1):

> The entity UUID provided is in an invalid format

This error means that the target selector being used did not find any targets, specifically for the `/execute` command (as the error would otherwise have been "failed to execute"). Therefore there were not any players with a "holdingTorch" score of 0.

If you are not setting the player's score to 0 first, then they will not have a score at all to detect. You would need to force their score to be 0, such as setting it to 0 before setting it to 1:

```
/scoreboard players set @a holdingTorch 0
/scoreboard players set @a holdingTorch 1 {SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:torch"}}
```

You should **not** be using `@p` as the nested selector when the executor is `@a` in order to target the executing player. The only selector that can target dead players is `@a`, so by causing dead players to remove night vision from `@p`, they will not remove it from themselves but instead remove it from the nearest-living player to their dead body.

The fix is to use the same selector, such as `@e[type=Player]` as the executor with `@p` as the nested selector, or `@a` as executor and `@a[c=1]` as nested selector.

```
/execute @e[type=Player,score_holdingTorch=0] ~ ~ ~ /effect @p minecraft:night_vision 0
```

Or:

```
/execute @a[score_holdingTorch=0] ~ ~ ~ /effect @a[c=1] minecraft:night_vision 0
```

---

If you're using 1.9+, you will want to use scoreboard "tags" instead of scores. These are more efficient to use and will not bloat `scoreboard.dat` as the tags are saved on the entities themselves:

```
/scoreboard players tag @a[tag=holdingTorch] remove holdingTorch
/scoreboard players tag @a add holdingTorch {SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:torch"}}

/execute @a[tag=!holdingTorch] ~ ~ ~ /effect @a[c=1] minecraft:night_vision 0
```